# Can I const-access CPython objects without GIL?

Tags: performance, cpython, gil

### Context and motivation

This is a question about releasing GIL in CPython while still working with Python objects, but in a limited way.

For performance reasons, I need to jump into GIL-less mode while maintaining read-only access to existing Python objects. The objects are guaranteed to exist throughout, and no other thread mutates them (no deletes, appends etc). In other words, they are "const" for all practical purposes, no ref counting needed, no dynamic allocations take place.

---

### Question

Assume we have a native Python object on input, such as a `list`, `dict` or `int`. We can work with this object as `PyObject *` using the C API, as normal.

Q: Is it safe to release GIL and then call read-only ("const") functions on this object? For example, call `PyList_GET_ITEM(lst, 0)`, `PyInt_AS_LONG(i)` or `PyDict_GetItem(dct, key)`?

If not, why not?

More generally, what is the CPython contract regarding (lack of) object mutation and dynamic allocations, and the need for synchronization via GIL?

---

### What I tried

I created a Python list of integers, then released the GIL, iterated over the list elements using standard `PyList_Size` and `PyList_GET_ITEM`, summed the integer values inside, re-acquired GIL. All worked fine, results came out correct. No need to incref/decref anything, since no Python objects were created, deleted or mutated.

But this experiment is no proof of course—there may be side effects or limitations.

---

### What I'm NOT asking

- whether I can release GIL and work with Python objects
- what is the GIL
- where is the CPython documentation
- what will some non-CPython implementation do

Comment: You mention `dict` in the question? Do you have any suitable "const" functions in mind, because I'd guess there aren't any?

Comment: @DavidW `PyDict_GetItem`, `PyDict_GetItemString`, `PyDict_Size`, `PyDict_Contains`. Not sure if they implement some caching internally, which would mess up the constness.

Comment: `GetItem` and `Contains` surely have to call the equals operator at some point which will return a Python object. I suspect `GetItemString` creates a temporary Python string (needs reference counting). `Size` might work...

Comment: Also, for `list` of `int`, have you considered using `array.array`, which supports genuine 100% safe GIL-free access through the buffer interface. (I know this doesn't answer the question...)

Comment: I just tried `PyDict_GetItem` outside of GIL on a unicode=>int `dict`, and it worked fine too. In what ways would you expect this to fail, where should I look / trigger the problem?

Comment: So [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b75228700e0077d8bf2636e74733389514b4b2f/Objects/dictobject.c#L1288) shows a number of C API calls. There's changes to the error state (mostly if the key isn't found). It calls `PyThreadState_GET`, for which the documentation explicitly says "must have the GIL". Most of the work is hidden in `dk_lookup`, which is a little harder to trace. I could see why you might get away with it, but it really looks dodgy in a way that `list` doesn't.

Comment: I traced `dk_lookup` down to [dictobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L821) and it seems no Python objects are created, at least for unicode keys. So should be safe. Not sure what `PyThreadState_GET` is about…